# "ORA-01861: literal does not match format string" Error in PL/SQL

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle11g, to-date

Can someone help me understand what the following code line is doing wrong?

`res_start_time_ := to_date(to_char(account_date_, 'YYYYMMDD ') || sched_ftime_, 'YYYYMMDD HH24:MI');`

`res_start_time_` and `account_date_` are of DATE type.

`sched_ftime_` is VARCHAR2 type and it can be NULL.

In a test scenario, I get the `ORA-01861: literal does not match format string` error when there is a value for `account_date_` and NULL for `sched_ftime_`.

Can someone explain to me what I am doing wrong and how I can get rid of this error?

Comment: @GordonLinoff In Oracle a `DATE` data type **always** has year, month, day, hour, minute and second components. It is perfectly valid to use `TO_DATE` with a time component.

Comment: I cannot replicate the error [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=2c5694c14a26de435aa6c08c7846924a). Please [edit] your question to include a [MRE] with a complete (minimal) PL/SQL block that we can execute to demonstrate the error so that we can replicate your issue.

Comment: Do you have some sample values. Usually it is not needed to convert from DATE to VARCHAR2 back and forth.

Comment: @MT0 try to add `trunc(sysdate)` (or anything else, like date) to `sched_ftime_` and not `NULL`.. and Voilà.

Comment: @Georgy The question states "I get the ORA-01861: literal does not match format string error when there is a value for `account_date_` and NULL for `sched_ftime_`." Therefore if you use a non-`NULL` value for `sched_ftime_` then the inputs do not match the question which states it is a `NULL` value.

Answer (score 1):

The source code is attempting to form a string that can be converted to a date having both a day value and a time-of-day value.

This  `to_char(account_date_, 'YYYYMMDD ')` converts a date value into a 9 character string ending with a space which permits use of string concatenation of what should be  value containing hours and minutes. Once concatenated it then attempts to convert that into a date value accurate to a minute.

However the error encountered will occur if a non-null value of `sched_ftime_` isn't in a form that can be transformed to HH24:MI e.g. `'123456'` is to long to be interpreted as only hours and minutes.

This can be replicated:

```
ALTER SESSION SET NLS_DATE_FORMAT = 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS';
DECLARE
  res_start_time_ DATE;
  account_date_   DATE := TRUNC(SYSDATE);
  sched_ftime_    VARCHAR2(20) := '123456'; /* this value fails */
BEGIN
  res_start_time_ := to_date(
                       to_char(account_date_, 'YYYYMMDD ') || sched_ftime_,
                       'YYYYMMDD HH24:MI'
                     );
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(res_start_time_);
END;
/

ORA-01861: literal does not match format string
ORA-06512: at line 6
```

However a shorter value e.g. `'1234'` can be interpreted as hours and minutes:

```
DECLARE
  res_start_time_ DATE;
  account_date_   DATE := TRUNC(SYSDATE);
  sched_ftime_    VARCHAR2(20) := '1234'; /* this value works */
BEGIN
  res_start_time_ := to_date(
                       to_char(account_date_, 'YYYYMMDD ') || sched_ftime_,
                       'YYYYMMDD HH24:MI'
                     );
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(res_start_time_);
END;
/

1 rows affected

dbms_output:
2021-08-27 12:34:00
```

Hence I suggest you protect the conversion into a date by limiting the length of your second parameter e.g. to 4 characters perhaps using `substr()`

```
DECLARE
  res_start_time_ DATE;
  account_date_   DATE := TRUNC(SYSDATE);
  sched_ftime_    VARCHAR2(20) := '123456'; /* this value gets truncated */
BEGIN
  res_start_time_ := to_date(
                       to_char(account_date_, 'YYYYMMDD ') 
                               || substr(sched_ftime_,1,4),
                       'YYYYMMDD HH24:MI'
                     );
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(res_start_time_);
END;
/
```

You may need other validations on that varchar2 value such that they are all digits as well. Or, if you are including the colon into the hour & minutes value then the overall length needs to be 5 chars. In short you need to vet the hours and minutes so that they are logical and valid.

nb: Kudos to MT0 for the source db<>fiddle which I extended [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=b5b3c510655dcd90a285caa34624ce25)

Comment: This gives the expected error but it does not match the input conditions in the OP's question as they state that "I get the `ORA-01861: literal does not match format string` error when there is a value for `account_date_` and NULL for `sched_ftime_`." This is answering for when `sched_ftime_` is non-`NULL`.

Comment: The question states `it can be null` , not that it is null. As you demonstrated the error isn't triggered by a null in that parameter, and as shown above the error occurs when not null and incapable of being converted to HH24:MI The OP needs to validate the second parameter for that format compatibility when not null.

Answer (score 0):

The source of the issue is you are allowing the time component (`sched_ftime_`) to assume values that you do not know the *exact format* before hand. You can do this, but it comes with a coding requirement. You need to establish the permissible and then derive the FORMAT SPECIFICATION at run time, and throw an error if the value does not match a permissible pattern. What is permissible and the validation is as simple or complicated as you want. As a demonstration the following function looks for 5 patterns:hh24mi, hh24miss, hh24:mi, hh24:mi:ss, and null. For those it returns the appropriate date, for anything else it returns a application defined exception.

```
create or replace 
function get_actual_date_time( account_date_  date
                             , sched_ftime_   varchar2
                             ) 
  return date
is 
  k_format_base          constant varchar2(8)  := 'yyyymmdd';
  k_bad_time_format_msg  constant varchar2(32) := ' invalid time specification.';  
  -- declare regexp for valid time formats 
  k_regx_time_hh24mm     constant varchar2(7)  := '^\d{4}$';
  k_regx_time_hh24mmss   constant varchar2(7)  := '^\d{6}$'; 
  k_regx_time_hh24mm_s   constant varchar2(11) := '^\d\d:\d\d$'; 
  k_regx_time_hh24mmss_s constant varchar2(16) := '^\d\d:\d\d:\d\d$';  
  
  -- declare actual format specification corresponding to valid format
  k_fmt_time_hh24mm      constant varchar2(6)  := 'hh24mi';
  k_fmt_time_hh24mmss    constant varchar2(8)  := 'hh24miss'; 
  k_fmt_time_hh24mm_s    constant varchar2(7)  := 'hh24:mi';
  k_fmt_time_hh24mmss_s  constant varchar2(10) := 'hh24:mi:ss';
  
  l_time_format varchar2(16); 
begin     
  case when sched_ftime_ is null then
            l_time_format := null;
       when regexp_like ( sched_ftime_,k_regx_time_hh24mm) then
            l_time_format := k_fmt_time_hh24mm; 
       when regexp_like ( sched_ftime_,k_regx_time_hh24mmss) then
            l_time_format := k_fmt_time_hh24mmss;  
       when regexp_like ( sched_ftime_,k_regx_time_hh24mm_s) then
            l_time_format := k_fmt_time_hh24mm_s;  
       when regexp_like ( sched_ftime_,k_regx_time_hh24mmss_s) then
            l_time_format := k_fmt_time_hh24mmss_s;  
       else 
           raise_application_error( -20109,'''' || sched_ftime_ || '''' || k_bad_time_format_msg); 
  end case; 
       
  return to_date(to_char(account_date_,k_format_base) || sched_ftime_ 
                , k_format_base || l_time_format);
end get_actual_date_time;
```

Keep in mind the above is **an example only** and there are many enhancement to be made. For example is will accept time specification of `99:99:99` even though it is obviously a invalid time specification. But it fits the validation for `'^\d\d:\d\d:\d\d$'`. Neither does it attempt to validate the valid time specification `06:45 PM`. See [fiddle here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=063f69a94c5ea8999e73de758c98edc4).